# Proving there are arbitrarily large limit ordinals

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I want to prove that there are arbitrarily large limit ordinals. What does arbitrarily large limit ordinals mean?

I think the idea of the proof of the statement is by using contradiction. So, we suppose that there are not arbitrarily large limit ordinals and we denote the largest limit ordinal by lets's say $\alpha$. Then I show that there can be another limit ordinal that is larger than $\alpha$. So, this is a contradiction and by the same argument it can be shown that basically there are arbitrarily large limit ordinals. Now, I think my argument shows that there are infinitely many large limit ordinals. I'm not sure I understand it.

Comment: "Arbitrarily large" means that for any ordinal $a$, there is a limit ordinal at least as large as $a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x\in On$ then $x+\omega=\bigcup \{x+n:n\in \omega\}$ is a limit ordinal which is larger than $x$.